# Problem validating XML against DTD in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, dtd

This has been bugging me for a couple days.  I'm trying to load a XML from an uploaded file to into an XmlDocument object and get the following yellow-screen-of-death:

```
For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the ProhibitDtd property on XmlReaderSettings to false and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.
```

Here's my code.  You can clearly see I'm setting ProhibitDtd to false.

```
public static XmlDocument LoadXml(FileUpload fu)
{
    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
                       {
                           ProhibitDtd = false, 
                           ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD
                       };
    var sDtdPath = string.Format(@"{0}", HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/includes/dtds/2.3/archivearticle.dtd"));
    settings.Schemas.Add(null, sDtdPath);

    var r = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(fu.PostedFile.InputStream), settings);
    var document = new XmlDocument();
    document.Load(r);
    return document;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `XmlResolver=null` to your `XmlReaderSettings`. This will prevent the xmlDocument from trying to access the DTD. If you need to validate, do that in a separate operation.